# What's the better Dockerfile command for very large install file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Current Dockerfile as following:

```
FROM centos
ADD install_10GB.tgz /opt/tmp
RUN /opt/tmp/setup.bin && rm -rf /opt/tmp/*
```

When I run `docker build -t my_image .`, it require much time to send the tgz file into docker's cache, I wish to reduce this time.
The docker image will increase because the tgz too large even the final disk usage in contain is about 1GB.

My problem is how to reduce the image size to near 1GB?
This install_10GB.tgz is generated by ourselves, if I want to save a layer, should I setup a a local web server to do that? Or, there is other Dockerfile command could use to just grab this file from my local disk without add extra layer.

Comment: Newer docker versions have a `--squash` option for the build command. This helps with the image size. However the transfer time for the build context remains the same.

Comment: Can you retrieve your tgz into the image from the web somewhere? An artifact repository, code repo, etc? Using curl would allow you to save a layer.

Comment: If your `tgz` is not using compression then you can use `docker build --compress -t my_image .` but that would still send the file to context. So if you want to save time you should use the approach @BMitch mentioned which is to launch a simple server which can serve the file and get the file using `curl` or `wget` during the build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine other two answers, the tips is

1. download from local web server
2. use multiple `FROM` command and `FROM ... AS` to make it clear
3. use `COPY --from` command on last stage
4. use .dockerignore

This method may be improved by removing the 172.17.0.1 IP, but I don't know how.

.dockerignore for ignore the big file sending to docker cache

```
*.tgz
```

build.sh to setup a local web server

```
python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 # simple web server
docker build -t my_image .
pkill python2 # kill the simple web server
```

Dockerfile with 'extract' as first stage name

```
FROM centos AS extract
RUN cd /opt/tmp && curl http://172.17.0.1:8888/install_10GB.tgz | tar -xzf -
RUN /opt/tmp/setup.bin
# assume the result files put on /usr/local/mypackage

FROM centos
COPY --from=extract /usr/local/mypackage /usr/local/mypackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Host your file install_10GB.tgz in simple server and get it in RUN command using curl or wget then you can use it without adding extra layer.This way, image size will be less compared to earlier one.

Example:

```
FROM centos
RUN cd /opt/tmp && curl -XGET 'server/install_10GB.tgz' && setup.bin && rm -rf /opt/tmp/*
```

Comment: Why is that? doesn't curl also create a layer?

Comment: In RUN command only, use curl command to download file.Since it is temporary file, once it fulfills its purpose it can be removed within same RUN command.Edited same in answer.

Comment: Such solution is creating a docker layer with a huge file in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds) with two FROM commands. The Final image would only contain all layers after the second From. This way you could have a small image and not have to rm the large file. Check the link to the documentation for more details.

Here an example of a multistage build:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, to improve your answer, could you directly show out what's proper sample Docerfile to keep it on stackoverflow instead of just a link?

Comment: I added an example. Although for more details a google search or my link should be used :)